# Boostrap Carousel with Knockout bindings - can't make nested bindings work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, carousel

I'm trying to put some Knockout content in a Bootstrap Carousel.

I need to get the code within the comments 'this is the code I'm having trouble with' (via the fiddle link below) to repeat to match the number of pages in 'pageCount' but it will not, I'm presuming becuase of the data bindings in the slide content. I can't work out what I need to do or add in the view model. The number of pages will vary, so I can't make static slides.

Plain text context with no bindings repeats to match the number contained in 'pageCount' as desired.

Sorry that I can not show database content in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ian_smithz/eC3tX/1/).

**Html**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="feature-bg-image" id="content">
        <script>
            $('.carousel').carousel({

            })
        </script>
        <p> I need to get the code within the comments 'this is the code I'm having troublw with' below to repeat to match the number of pages in 'pageCount' but it will not because of the data bindings. I can't work out what I need to do or add in the view model. </p>
        <p>Plain text context with no bindings repeats to match the number containe in 'pageCount' as desired </p>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-wrap="false">
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <!-- this is the code I'm having troublw with -->
                    <!-- ko foreach: new Array(pageCount()) -->
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="feature-item-container" data-bind="foreach: features">
                            <span
                                data-bind="badge: badgeUrl, popover: { trigger: 'hover',  html: true, placement: 'left auto' }">
                                <a data-placement='left' data-bind="attr: { href: target }">
                                    <img class="feature-item" name="feature_item"
                                         data-bind="attr: { src: icon, alt: name }">
                                </a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- end this is the code I'm having troublw with -->

                    <!-- ko foreach: new Array(pageCount()) -->
                    <div class="item">
                        <P>
                            This item repeats to match the number of pages in 'pageCount'
                            but the content above doesn't. I can't work out why after googling all week and looking through SO questions.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-home" data-slide="prev" rel="nofollow">
                    <span data-bind="click: previousPage, style: { color: page() > 1 ? '#222' : '#999' }">
                        <</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-home" data-slide="next" rel="nofollow">
                    <span data-bind="click: nextPage, style: { color: page()"
                    < pageCount() ? '#222' : '#999' }">></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <!-- ko foreach: new Array(pageCount()) -->
                <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-bind='attr: { "data-slide-to": $index() }'></li>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function FeaturesViewModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.limit = 2;
        self.page = ko.observable(1);
        self.pageCount = ko.observable(1);  
        self.features = ko.observableArray();

        self.refresh = function() { 
            $.get('/api/features?page=' + self.page() + '&limit=' + self.limit, function(data) {
                self.features(data.features);
                self.pageCount(data.pageCount);
            });
        };

        self.previousPage = function() {
            self.page( self.page() - 1 );
            if( self.page() < 1 ) self.page( 1 );
            self.refresh();
        };

        self.nextPage = function() {
            self.page( self.page() + 1 );
            if( self.page() > self.pageCount() ) self.page( self.pageCount() );
            self.refresh();
        };      
    }

    $(function() {

        var featuresModel = new FeaturesViewModel();    
        ko.applyBindings(featuresModel);
        featuresModel.refresh();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look on Google Groups Knockout forum and picked up a clue to solve my problem. I added '$parent' to 'foreach: features' e.g. 'foreach: $parent.features'. Thank you to the admins for your time and for approving my question anyway (I know the code example probably isn't perfect but I did not write it originally).